# Install Google Chrome with YUM on Fedora 14

Tags: chrome

I'm trying to install chrome in fedora 14..
When i run this:

```
yum install google-chrome-stable
```

I'm getting error like:

```
Error: google-chrome-stable conflicts with libX11-1.3.4-4.fc14.i686
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-43.0.2357.125-1.i386 (google)
       Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-43.0.2357.125-1.i386 (google)
       Requires: libnss3.so(NSS_3.14.3)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest**
```

How do I install this?

Answer (score 1):

Fedora 14 is rather old, consider upgrading it if possible.

```
$ sudo yum install fedora-upgrade 
$ sudo fedora-upgrade
```

Chrome 43 is quite new, it's no surprise that its dependencies conflict with your system's

Comment: I used `yum install fedora-upgrade` as a root but it given **No package fedora-upgrade available.**